# Keep getting same value from jQuery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, src

I have two problems.

1. I have a jQuery array which stores the URL's for images. Everything was working fine a few minutes ago, but now it's not. I have the following code for the images:

   var images = ["link1","link2","etc","etc"];
   index=0;

this to display them when you click their thumbnails:

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(){
$('.large_view').prepend('<img src="'+images[index]+'" width="450px"/>');
});
```

and this to show the previous/next images in the array:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
         index = (index===0)?(images.length-1):(index-1);
          $('.large_view img').attr('src',images[index]);
         });

$('.previous').click(function(){
           index = (index==images.length-1)?0:(index+1);
           $('.large_view img').attr('src',images[index]);
           });
```

My problem is that when I click a thumbnail, the same image (the first one in the array) always shows up. After that I can change the image properly with my next/previous buttons.

2. When I display the images in my array with code that includes the following, it shows up backwards, from the last item in the array to the first one: `for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++)`

P.S. the only reason the code inside `.previous` and `.next` are backwards is because the array is somehow backwards, like I said.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that when any thumbnail is clicked, `index` will be at its original value of 0, which is what's always making the first one show up. To fix this, you'll need to determine the corresponding index from whichever thumbnail was clicked (perhaps using `$(this).attr('data-image-index')`, if you stuffed the index into an attribute like that).

The second problem is that you want to use `.append` instead of `.prepend` in the `for` loop to tack each new thumbnail onto the *end* of the set instead of the *beginning*.

Also, the click handlers for `.next` and `.previous` appear to be backwards.

And you might want to use `$('.large_view').html(...)` instead of `$('.large_view').prepend(...)` if you only want one large picture to be displayed at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

1) your index is 0, so you are going to get the first image every time. 
this line

```js
$('.large_view').prepend('<img src="'+images[index]+'" width="450px"/>');
```

should be changed, to reference the index of the clicked thumbnail instead of the variable called index. so something like

```js
$('.large_view').prepend('<img src="'+ $(this).attr("index") +'" width="450px"/>');
```

You will add the index attr when creating the thumbnails, for example:

```js
for( var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
  var thumbnails = '<label class="align">' + '<img class="thumbnail" src="'+images[i]+'" index="' + i + '"/></label>';

  $('.gallery').prepend(thumbnails);

}
```

2) for your second problem, you are using prepend, which as the name implies PREpends. you will want to use append() to get them in the forward sequence as you want.